# how to add the icon to the right of a phone number in html?

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm trying to add the flaticon to the right of a phone number like the following:

```html
<a href="tel: +000 000 000 000"><span class="icon flaticon-phone-call-1"> 
</span><b> +000 000 000 000</a>
```

I also tried to make it like this:

```html
<a href="tel: +000 000 000 000"><b> 000 000 000 000 <span class="icon 
flaticon-phone-call-1"></span></a>
```

but all didn't work and the icon always will align to the left.

Is there any step that I missed to make it works?

Answer (score 1):

Because it can be useful for someone:

✆ [+1 999 999 999](https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1999999999)

```html
&#9990; <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1999999999">+1 999 999 999</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an unclosed `<b>` tag in your code that is causing you an issue.

You haven't included css, but here's a snippet of a right-aligned flaticon, which seems to be what you want. I positioned the flaticon using `background-position` css. I included `font-weight:bold` in this same css, as the `<b>` tag indicated to me that you wish the text to be bold. It's neater, however, if you include font-weight in your css, instead of adding in an extra html tag.

Hope this helps

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: auto;
  padding-right: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.flaticon-phone-call-1 {
  font-weight:bold;
  background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126509.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center right;
}
```

```html
Tel: <a href="+000 000 000 000"><span class="icon flaticon-phone-call-1">+000 000 000 000</span></a>
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, Thank you for your reply. I see that the problem is with numbers. It does mess the order of code. Can I put it inside a container that will keep the format as it is?

Comment: @Alex what do you mean by "mess with the order of the code"? What do you want to put in a container - the icon or the whole link? You could feasibly do either.

Comment: I mean it makes the code unorganised and out of order because when I tried to put for example the word "Tel" before number it does works but when I removed the "Tel" it returned to float in the left or in the middle of numbers. Also I tried to add a location name with location flaticon it works perfectly and float at the right without any problem, that's what makes me guess that the main problem is with numbers. I don't know if there is any solution to this or I have to put a word before numbers.

Comment: @Alex I don't know why you include a word in a hyperlink [or why you would use a hyperlink instead of a call button]. Including both numeric and alphanumeric characters will affect the functionality if what you want is for the user to make a phone call on click. Re-adjust  your code to take out the word from the hyperlink. You can format the word however you want. You can put it in a span tag with a class or id to style it if you wish

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo elements to do this.

```
.phone-class {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
  }

  .phone-class::before {
      display: inline-block;
      font-style: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      text-rendering: auto;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
      font-weight: 900;
      content: " \f095";
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      margin-left: 12px;
   }
<a class="phone-class" href="tel: +000 000 000 000">
```

+000 000 000 000

I used font awesome for the image of phone you can use any icon library just change the font-family and content . you can also put an image to achieve the same.

Before using this solution include fontawesome 5 link into your html head